# Search for names in an assosiative array php

Tags: php, arrays, search, preg-replace, associative-array

I have an array like this

```
  $_SESSION['list'] = array(
 'Romero' => 2,
 'Ronaldinho' => 4,
  'ronaldo'  =>8,
  'messi' => 20
);
```

Now if i enter a string `$str="ro"` i want to search the `$str` in `$_SESSION['list']`
so that it will **return** me

```
$id[0]=>2
$id[1]=> 4
$id[2]=> 9
```

and

```
$name[0]=> 'Romero'
$name[1]=> 'Ronaldinho'
$name[2]=> 'ronaldo'
```

How can i possibly do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @cept0: remarks that offer cynicism rather than helpful criticism aren't particularly constructive, and in any case they are often not well understood, as here. Is your point that the OP is not an expert programmer? If so, note that beginners are welcome here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop through the array and see if your search string is present in each index.

```
$id = array();
$name = array();

foreach($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $value)
{
    if(strpos(strtolower($key), strtolower($str)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $id[] = $value;
        $name[] = $key;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/c9Tdv)

Answer (score 1):

you can foreach through `$_SESSION['list']` comparing keys to `$str`. if comparison is true, `array_push` key and value to your new arrays.

Comment: nope. well, not until you provide code example of what you've tried.